# if else function issue about returning result based on original data frame

Tags: r

If I have the below data frame

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("sam", "ken", "mary", "kate"),
                 state = c("dead", "dead", "alive", "dead"))
```

I would like to create a new binary variable named success that is equal to 1 if the people die and to 0 if people survive. Like this:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("sam", "ken", "mary", "kate"),
                 state = c("dead", "dead", "alive", "dead"),
                 result = c(0, 0, 1, 0))
```

How can I write the commend in R using the  `ifelse` function? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `as.numeric(df$V2 == "alive")`

Answer (score 1):

To learn more about data transformation in R, I recommend https://www.tidyverse.org/learn/

Specifically http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html

```r
df <- data.frame(name = letters[1:4], state = c("dead", "dead", "alive", "dead"))

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df %>%
  mutate(result = if_else(state == "alive", 1, 0))
#>   name state result
#> 1    a  dead      0
#> 2    b  dead      0
#> 3    c alive      1
#> 4    d  dead      0
```